# I'm trying to define a Variable that takes two user inputs and divides the two

Tags: python-3.10

```py
1.def a(attempts,completions):
2.    attempts(),completions()
3.    return attempts / completions
4.
5.# add inputs 
6.a(input,input)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
#Basically, it says you can't use the division with two functions.
I have tried multiple different methods to solve the issue of defined integer variables when doing mathematics.
Examples of my Failures:

```py
1.def a(attempts,completions):
2.    attempts / completions
3.    return attempts(),completions()
4.
5.a(input, input)
```

Errors:
line 6 in  a(input, input)
line 2 attempts / completions TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'builtin_function_or_method'

#I have been wracking my brain over this and I've rewritten the code so many times that I decided to ask the community for help, please and thank you to anyone who responds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to to read the input for `attemps` and `completion` first with [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input). You can not call e. g.,`completions`, as it is no function.

```py
def div(attempts,completions):
    """
    calculate percentage of successful completions.
    """
    return attempts / completions

# call function
div(int(input("attemps:")),int(input("completions:")))
```

**Note:** You may want to add error checking to prevent division by zero.